# Is leaving at 21:55 on the day before a B-1 visa expires considered overstaying?

Tags: usa, visa-expiration

I am on a B-1 US visa and have been here for nearly six months. My passport is stamped till 9th November. I am leaving to go home on 8th November at 9:55pm.

Will this be overstaying the visa as it is so close or will it be fine?

Comment: That's 26 hours! I think you will be OK.

Comment: "Overstaying" means remaining in a country when your visa is no longer valid. Leaving while your visa is still valid is, by definition, not overstaying.

Comment: When your visa expires has absolutely nothing to do with how long you can stay. You can enter the US on the day that your visa expires, and be admitted for the normal time that that status is admitted for, with your visa being expired the entire time.

Answer (score 11):

It will be fine, especially if leaving by air, because, although the US does not have exit border control, the airline will pass on your info to the CBP.

The date written on the passport stamp is the day on which you have to leave at the latest. So if it says 9 November, your flight must leave at 23:59 on 9 November at the latest

Nevertheless, I always advise people to check [this Website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) once you're home. It should list one arrival and one departure. If the departure does **not** appear within a week, the airline may have done something wrong, in which case, to avoid being wrongfully classified as an overstayer, you should send a copy of the passport, visa and US entry stamp, together with as much evidence of your departure as possible (such as original boarding passes, passport stamps, card transactions from outside the US) to:

> Coleman Data Solutions
>
> 3043 Sanitarium Road, Suite 2
>
> Akron, OH  44312
>
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
>
> United states

But like I said, you will **not** be overstaying with your schedule

Comment: spectacular link you provided there!

Answer (score 6):

You are required to depart by midnight on November 9 - you have enough margin of safety. ([See](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/43664/4995))

Comment: While your answer is correct, the link you gave talks about the _visa_ dates, rather than the admission stamp dates.